# The default action of a file input disappears while parent div return false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a parent `div` which contains an `input` element, and every time the parent `div` is clicked, it returns `false`.

```
<div class="media-asset">
    <input  type="file" name="picture-label" >
</div>
```

```js
$('body').on({
        click:function(){
            return false;
        }
},'.media-asset');
```

The problem is when the parent `div` returns `false`, the default action of a file `input` is gone, and it won't prompt the user to upload a file. Is it possible to manually trigger the default action of a file input?

```
$('body').on({
            click:function(){
                //manually trigger the file input
                return false;
            }
    },'.media-asset input');
```

The reason I let the parent `div` to return false is when the user click outside of the parent `div`, it would hide the parent `div`, and while the user click inside of the parent `div`, it would not hide itself.

Comment: the reason I'm binding to the body is because I load the media-asset using ajax

Comment: i don't understand why you need to return false, do you have another handler somewhere for hiding the div which is being triggered as a result of propagation? if so, i'd suggest you make the changes in there, and not add unnecessary handlers only to prevent propagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually trigger it. Specify [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) on the `'.media-asset input'` click event and remove the `return false` from that as well:

> #### event.stopPropagation()
>
> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
>
> — [event.stopPropagation() - jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$('body').on({
  click:function(){
    return false;
  }
},'.media-asset');

$('body').on({
  click:function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
},'.media-asset input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-asset">
    <input  type="file" name="picture-label" >
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Not until now do I know how stopPropagation works